# Работа с базой данных и шаблонами в Delphi

Tags: шаблоны, delphi

Как можно реализовать следующее.

- Выводить по шаблону данные, например:

> Витя взял %num1% яблока, а Максим %num2%. Сколько яблок у них вместе?

- Ввожу ответ и его проверяем, в зависимости от num1+num2.
- Как сделать БД из вопросов?

%num% - рандомное число.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а может так попробовать?
делаем шаблон:

```
const 
Shablon = 'Витя взял %d яблока, а Максим %d. Сколько яблок у них вместе? ';
```

и обрабатывать шаблон таким образом:

```
str:= Format(Shablon,[num1, num2])
```

где num1 и num2 некоторые числа, мб даже результаты запроса

Comment: ответ принят спустя год. жесть

Answer (score 1):

В простейшем случае база данных не нужна, достаточно текстового файла, в котором подряд идут строки с вопросами.

> Сколько будет %num%+%num%?
> Верно ли тождество %num%+%num%=%num%?
> ...

Задача сводится к тому, чтобы

- прочитать строку из файла,
- найти вхождения подстроки %num% и заменить их на случайные величины,
- перевести запись вида %num%+%num% в формулу, вычислимую на Delphi.

Запись-чтение из файла - стандартно с помощью WriteLn/ReadLn и т.д. Генерация случайных величин - Random. Замена подстроки - StringReplace. Чтобы правильно воспринять формулу, лучше ограничитья определенным набором заранее известных выражений, тогда из можно промаркировать и найти поиском, иначе придется прибегать к JIT-компиляции и тому подобным сложным вещам.